# CSS selector for locating specific row in a table: Confused about nth-type/nth-child

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a table which can have elements added to it and I need to be able to locate specific rows of the table for Selenium automation testing. I don't care about the first two rows -- just the ones that have class names starting with 'something'. I tried these as locators to pick the first table row that has a class name starting with 'something'. Selenium throws exceptions trying to interact with these elements. What am I doing wrong....

`div.elements table.table tbody tr.something:nth-child(1)`
`div.elements table.table tbody tr.something:nth-of-type(1)`

```
<div class="elements">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="no-data hide">
            <tr class="no-data hide"></tr>
            <tr class="something something_fa4743bd-0ada-4c74-bae0-351ddc322f7d">
            <tr class="something something_e357d71c-559f-4ea1-bc7d-489537ab083e">
            <tr class="something something_71d6b3f7-df45-4283-a669-bfbcfccd7d0f">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is are the methods I'm having difficulty with. So basically, it is a data entry form. If you want to add another entry, you click a button, a new row appears. The method returns the row number of the new entry, so that further interaction with the new row can occur.

```
private static final String somethingEntryRowCss = "div.scrolling-table table.table tbody tr.hostname";

public final int clickAddSomethingButton() {
    int count = countEntries() + 1;
    addSomethingButton.click();

    ComponentLoader.waitForElementVisible(driver, 
            By.cssSelector(somethingEntryRowCss + ":nth-child(" + count
                    +")"));     
    return count;
}
```

Here is the `ComponentLoader.waitForElementVisible(driver, By)` method that checks to see if the new row is visible after clicking the button. It is timing out while waiting for the element to be visible:

```
public static final WebElement waitForElementVisible(final WebDriver driver, 
    final By locator) {

    try {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = setWait(driver);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
        break;
    } catch(NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        logger.trace("NoSuchElementException. Element is not visible.);
    } catch(TimeoutException toe) {
        logger.trace("TimeoutException. Element is not visible.);
    }
    return driver.findElement(locator);
}
```

Comment: Well **what** exception is it throwing?

Comment: It is a timeout exception that is thrown by a helper method. I have updated my question to add more information.

Comment: Actually, it seems that if I try to get the class name of the element inside the catch block for the timeout exception, I get a NoSuchElementException. So, the problem is essentially that there is no such element for the locator.

Answer (score 0):

Nor sure about correctness of java code, but this should look like

```
//This will return exactly first tr with class .something
IWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Css(".table .something"));
```

**LITTLE UPDATE**

Well, if again i correctly understood you =), and if you want to access to row by it's index you can try use next method

```
public void Test()
{
   var row2 = GetSomethingRow(1);
   //You can do anything now with this row   
   row2.getText();
}

public IWebElement GetSomethingRow(int index)
{
   var elements = driver.findElements(By.Css(".table .something"));
   return elements[index];
}
```

Comment: I can easily locate a web element matching that selector. I am trying to target a specific element using nth-of-type or nth-child.

Comment: Sorry don't understand. What element you want to target?

Comment: I want to be able to target a specific row. I need to write automated tests that add rows, remove rows, change the values in rows. I need to be able to specify a row number and get that element. I don't care about the two rows which have class names `no-data`. I want to be able to use my base css locator: `div.elements table.table tbody tr.something`  to get, for example, the second row that matches this locator, or the third or forth, etc.